# validate and update single attribute rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have the following in my user model

```
attr_accessible :avatar, :email

validates_presence_of :email
has_attached_file :avatar # paperclip

validates_attachment_size :avatar,
                          :less_than => 1.megabyte,
                          :message => 'Image cannot be larger than 1MB in size',
                          :if => Proc.new { |imports| !imports.avatar_file_name.blank? }
```

in one of my controllers, **I ONLY want to update and validate the avatar field *without updating and validating email*.**

How can I do this?

for example (this won't work)

```
if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
 # do something... 
end
```

I also tried with `update_attribute('avatar', params[:user][:avatar])`, but that would skip  the validations for avatar field as well.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457239/is-there-a-way-to-validate-a-specific-attribute-on-an-activerecord-without-instan/457313#457313

Comment: no, i think `mock.valid?` validates everything. I am looking to validate only one attribute.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could [validate the attribute by hand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457239/is-there-a-way-to-validate-a-specific-attribute-on-an-activerecord-without-instan/457313#457313) and use [`update_attribute`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_attribute), that [skips validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#skipping-validations). If you add [this to your `User`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457239/is-there-a-way-to-validate-a-specific-attribute-on-an-activerecord-without-instan/457313#457313):

```
def self.valid_attribute?(attr, value)
  mock = self.new(attr => value)
  if mock.valid?
    true
  else
    !mock.errors.has_key?(attr)
  end
end
```

And then update the attribute thusly:

```
if(!User.valid_attribute?('avatar', params[:user][:avatar])
    # Complain or whatever.
end
@user.update_attribute('avatar', params[:user][:avatar])
```

You should get your single attribute updated while only (manually) validating that attribute.

If you look at how Milan Novota's `valid_attribute?` works, you'll see that it performs the validations and then checks to see if the specific `attr` had issues; it doesn't matter if any of the other validations failed as `valid_attribute?` only looks at the validation failures for the attribute that you're interested in.

If you're going to be doing a lot of this stuff then you could add a method to User:

```
def update_just_this_one(attr, value)
    raise "Bad #{attr}" if(!User.valid_attribute?(attr, value))
    self.update_attribute(attr, value)
end
```

and use that to update your single attribute.

Comment: this would check for email validations too, just not avatar.

Comment: @Madhusudhan: You can set up the validation by hand and use `update_attribute`. Please see my update.

Comment: shouldn't line 4 in the logic above be "return !mock.errors.has_key?(attr)"?

Comment: @FelafelWaffle: Yes, there was a missing `!` in there. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 8):

A condition?

```
validates_presence_of :email, :if => :email_changed?
```

Comment: Brilliant.  Thank you, I didn't even realize you got these handy helper functions!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting a condition on the `validates_presence_of :email` ?

http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#M000083

Configuration options:

> if - Specifies a method, proc or string to call to determine if the validation should occur (e.g. :if => :allow_validation, or :if => Proc.new { |user| user.signup_step > 2 }). The method, proc or string should return or evaluate to a true or false value.
>
> unless - Specifies a method, proc or string to call to determine if the validation should not occur (e.g. :unless => :skip_validation, or :unless => Proc.new { |user| user.signup_step <= 2 }). The method, proc or string should return or evaluate to a true or false value.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you need this, because you have a multi-step wizard, where you first upload the avatar and the e-mail is filled in later.

To my knowledge, with your validations as they are, I see no good working solution. Either you validate all, or you update the avatar without validations. If it would be a simple attribute, you could check if the new value passes the validation seperately, and then update the model without validations (e.g. using `update_attribute`).

I can suggest two possible alternative approaches:

- either you make sure that the e-mail is always entered first, which I believe is not a bad solution. And then, with each save, the validation is met.
- otherwise, change the validation. Why would you declare a validation on a model, if there are records in the database that do not meet the validation? That is very counter-intuitive.

So I would propose something like this:

```
validate :presence_of_email_after_upload_avatar

def presence_of_email_after_upload_avatar
  # write some test, when the email should be present
  if avatar.present?
    errors.add(:email, "Email is required") unless email.present?
  end
end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: errors.add(:email, "Email is required") generates error = "Email Email is required". Change "Email is required" to  just "is required"

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution.
It keeps the same behaviour than **.valid?** method, witch returns true or false, and add errors on the model on witch it was called.

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  def valid_attributes?(attributes)
    mock = self.class.new(self.attributes)
    mock.valid?
    mock.errors.to_hash.select { |attribute| attributes.include? attribute }.each do |error_key, error_messages|
      error_messages.each do |error_message|
        self.errors.add(error_key, error_message)
      end
    end

    self.errors.to_hash.empty?
  end
end

> my_model.valid_attributes? [:first_name, :email] # => returns true if first_name and email is valid, returns false if at least one is not valid
> my_modal.errors.messages # => now contain errors of the previous validation
{'first_name' => ["can't be blank"]}
```